# Ping request not shown in Wireshark if no reply is received, how come?

Tags: ping, wireshark

When I ping a computer that exists and get a reply, both the request and reply will be shown in Wireshark (I have put icmp as filter).

However if I ping a computer that does not exist the request will not be shown. Obviously there will be no reply but how come the request is not shown?

Edit: Also, if I ping my own IP I will get a reply but no message in Wireshark.

I ping via a direct IP-address, not a hostname. I.e. "ping XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"

Comment: Do you see the ARP packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ping via hostname, first there will be a DNS lookup to retrieve the IP address. You will not find an IP address because pc doesn't exists, so Ping will not even try to send a request because it doesn't know where to send it to.

Comment: Correct, but in the initial question the user asked why the ping request was not visible. ARP is a stage before the ping request.

Comment: I am not pinging a hostname but a direct IP address.

Comment: I meant that fail on ARP stage will also result in ICMP packet not being issued. For example, ping on Linux prints Destination Host Unreachable in that case.

Comment: @BenVanHees Before the ip packet is able to be sent out, We need to know the MAC address of the ip if it is not broadcast. In this case, arp resolve always failed therefore the icmp request would not be sent.

Comment: @Jerry_Y I know :) Sorry if that was not clear. I guess that's the part user2257389 needs to know to understand why he's not seeing the initial ICMP request in Wireshark